# Comparing Nvarchar2 field with Varchar2 field in ORACLE database

Tags: oracle, type-conversion

so I have the table A with last_name column in varchar2 type, and a table B with last_name column in nvarchar2 type, I want to compare them to find differences

select *
from a
join b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
where CAST(lower(a.last_name) AS varchar2(100)) <> CAST(lower(a.last_name) AS varchar2(100))

but this brings me every row even when their last_name is the same

Comment: Your code has a typo (I assume), with the both cast/lower calls on the same table a - so would find now rows. With that fixed [it seems to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/I2IV6Hsy). Can you provide a [mre]? (And are you sure neither table has trailing whitespace; and the first table is varchar2, not char? Does trimming the values change the result?)

Comment: it was trailing whitespace thank you so much, triming the values solved the problem